# How do I use a Bluetooth-enabled smartphone as a 'Bluetooth Adapter' when it's connected to my PC via USB?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, usb, bluetooth

OK, so I bought an All-In-One PC from a wanker who told me it had Bluetooth. It doesn't have Bluetooth. I remember on my old PC I had a USB/Bluetooth Adapter that I could plug in to my PC's USB port and the PC was then able to do Bluetooth magics with other Bluetooth-enabled devices. However, that adapter no longer works (broken) and I've been to Dick Smith, JB, Harvey Norman, Coles, K-Mart, etc and nobody sells anything useful anymore so now I'm wondering if I can plug my phone into the PC's USB port and use the phone as an 'adapter' for Bluetooth, thus enabling the PC to have above said Bluetooth magics. Is this possible, and how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically this is impossible, since the phone won't allow this kind of access to the bluetooth-hardware on it. However, if you have a special use-case there might be a solution in the shape of an app for your smartphone that handles it (I can help you look if you tell me this use-case and the phone you use)

If you want native usb support for your laptop you'll have to find and buy a Bluetooth dongle I am affraid.

I would suggest to look for them online on eBay. They'll probably be cheap but have a long delivery time (it depends on where you live I guess...)

If I would be you I'd avoid the China/Hong-Kong ones.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks @MahNas, I went with your advice and got a dongle from eBay. An app would be good but I think I'd just prefer the dongle. Had to get it from ebay though as nobody sells them around here anymore. The only reason I wanted a Bluetooth adapter was so that I could implement Bluetooth features into my apps using the Bluetooth API but it's been a real hassle trying to find a dongle til now.