# Use Bluetooth-enabled phone as bluetooth adapter

Tags: windows-10, android, bluetooth

Has been asked 3 years ago, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/835299/how-do-i-use-a-bluetooth-enabled-smartphone-as-a-bluetooth-adapter-when-its-c), wondering if there's any advancements, using root or otherwise.

Using it as a receiver for a wii remote, so any audio/video specific workarounds won't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a Bluetooth-enabled smartphone as a 'Bluetooth Adapter' when it's connected to my PC via USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/835299/how-do-i-use-a-bluetooth-enabled-smartphone-as-a-bluetooth-adapter-when-its-c)